# Different Pseudo Clock for groups of Facts

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

I am new to drools / fusion (7.x) and am not sure how to solve this requirement.  Assume I have event objects as Event{long: timestamp, id: string} where id identifies a physical asset (like tractor) and timestamp represents the time the event fired relative to the asset.  In my scenario these Events do not arrive in my system in 'real-time', meaning they can be seconds, minutes or even days late.  And my rules system needs to monitor multiple assets.  Given this, when rules are evaluate the clock needs to be relative to the asset being monitored, it can't be a clock that spans assets.
I'm aware of Pseudo Clock, is there a way to assign Pseudo clocks per Asset?

My assumption is that a clock must always progress forward or temporal functions will not work properly.  Take for the example the following scenario:
Fact A for Asset 1 arrive at 1:00 it is inserted into memory and rules fired.  Then Fact B arrives for same Asset 1 at 2:00.  It too is inserted and rules fired.  Now Fact Z arrives for Asset 2 at 1:30 (- 30 minutes from clock).  I'm assuming I shouldn't simply progress the clock backwards and evaluate, furthermore I'd want to set the clock back to 2:00 since that was the "latest" data I received.  Now assume I am monitoring thousands of assets, all sending data at different times...

The best way I can think to address this is to keep a clock per asset and then save the engine state when each assets data is evaluated.  Can individual KieSession's have different clocks, or is it at a container level?

Sample rule: When Fact 1 arrives after Fact 2 for the same Asset.

Answer (score 1):

You're approaching the problem incorrectly. Regardless of whether you're using a realtime or psuedo clock, you're using *a* clock. You can't say "Fact #1 use clock A, and Fact #2 use clock B."

Instead you should be leveraging the [metadata tags for events](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-declarations-metadata-tags-ref_decision-engine), specifically the `@timestamp` tag. This tag indicates to Drools that a specific field inside of the event is actually the timestamp for the Event, rather than the actual time the fact enters working memory.

For example:

```
import com.example.SampleEvent

declare SampleEvent
  @role( event )
  // this field is actually in the object, it's not the time the fact was inserted
  @timestamp( createdDateTime ) 
end
```

Not knowing anything about what your rules are actually doing, the major issue I can foresee here is that if your rules rely on the temporal operators or define an expiry (`@expires`), they're not going to work and you'll need to redesign them. Especially for expirations: once an event expires, it is removed from working memory; when your out-of-band events come in any previously expired events are already gone and can't be worked against.

Of course that concern would be true regardless of whether you use `@timestamp` or your original "different psuedo clock" plan. Either way you're going to have to manage the fact that events *cannot* live forever in working memory -- you will eventually run out of resources and your system will crash. Events must be evicted at some point, so you'll need to design around that in both your models and your rules.

Comment: So then your question makes even less sense. @timestamp is the way you enter events "out of sync". You only have one clock, at the end of the day; timestamp allows you to customize when your event occurs.

Comment: I added additional details, as it was lengthy I didn't want to put it in a comment.